# setImageResource for Image Button from a class

Tags: android, android-activity, constructor, android-context, android-imagebutton

In Android M, I need to set an `ImageButton` to a specific resource in the drawable folder.
Which will which will work from the `MainActivity` where the view was declared.

I have a `second Activity` that needs to call a class with the method
being to select the correct resource using a switch statement.

I cannot get the reference to the ImageButton correctly into the called Class.

I am using a constructor to set the context within the class and have made the ImageButton mRecordImageButton object public, but still have the unresolved reference to object error for mRecordImageButton. (`unable to resolve symbol`).

Here is the code in the class. 
in the `MainActivity`

```
public ImageButton mRecordImageButton;
```

in the `ImageButtonProperties.java` class file

```
 package twistlogic.com.miwidget;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class ImageButtonProperties {
        Context context;

        public ImageButtonProperties() {
                this.context = context;                 // constructor
            }

        public void ImageButtonSym(EnumLists enumList) {

            switch (enumList) {
                case VIDEO_OFF:
                    (ImageButton) ((Activity)context).mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_black_18dp);
                    break;
             default:
            }


        }

    }
```

Thank for any help.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thank you for the assistance, I am just learning so your help is appreciated.
The constructor is being called now, when I check with the debugger, but I still have and unresolved reference to the button.

Call to the constructor as you suggested, I have it after setContentView

setContentView(twistlogic.com.miwidget.R.layout.activity_camera2_video_image);
final ImageButtonProperties properties = new ImageButtonProperties((this));

In the main class I have
    private ImageButton mRecordImageButton;
I also tried public, but that also didn't work

I call with:
    properties.ImageButtonSym(AppButtonStates.VIDEO_REC_ON);

the called class is

public class ImageButtonProperties {
    Context context;

```
public ImageButtonProperties(Context context) {
    this.context = context;          // constructor
}

public void ImageButtonSym(int appButtonStates) {
    switch (appButtonStates) {
        case AppButtonStates.VIDEO_REC_ON:
            (ImageButton) ((Activity)context).mRecordImageButton.setImageResource(twistlogic.com.miwidget.R.mipmap.btn_video_online);
            break;

    }
}
```

}

I was using as a guide, 'how to change text from another activity', but I still get the mRecordImageButton as an unresolved reference. Maybe I am not understanding the Context object. I thought that if I had the context, that all the objects in the view would be accessible. Is that an error in understanding?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is missing an argument, it should look this this:

```
 public ImageButtonProperties(Context context) {
        this.context = context; 
    }
```

and in the Activity call the constructor like this:

```
ImageButtonProperties properties = new ImageButtonProperties(this);
```

The way it is just now you're just assigning nothing to nothing. I'd be surprised if lint wasn't giving you a warning about it.